# Can Ubuntu repair windows 7 that won't boot?

Tags: boot, windows-7

So my old computers motherboard died and right in the middle of a windows boot. As you imagine, after buying a new and suitable rig windows 7 will not boot. windows gets to the "windows starting up" animation and restarts. When the computer restarts it goes to the startup repair which says it cannot be repaired. However, with ubuntu installed, all HDD files are accounted for and all components work well. Is there a way for ubuntu to repair the booting process without compromising any files on the HDD? Thanks!

Comment: Try to use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu) , I think it can repair some Windows boot problems also.

Comment: You could, alternatively download a copy of windows 7 from the links [here on superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd) and try to fix it from the tools windows has. This might mess up your ubuntu install but back up first

Comment: I don't think this question is on topic.

Comment: @Parto partially agree, but it _can be answered here in the current form_ though the answer is definitely No ;)

Comment: @NikTh it can repair only initial boot problems, it can't fix Windows BSOD caused by wrong chipset record in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that since the motherboard died there is some conflict with the Windows installation process which may have left residual files on the hard disk drive which can't be removed with no OS installed.

Accessing Ubuntu on the system doesn't go over the Windows install it uses the hardware to run the OS. You could possible format the Windows partitions on the drives and try to reinstall Windows after you have done that.

Answer (score 0):

i think a recovery image would do the work, all you need is to download it and burn it on a CD and launch the system reparation procedure

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is *No*. Ubuntu is not designed either to fix Windows errors nor to clear it's trash. The reason why does Ubuntu work is that Linux surpasses Windows in this way: it doesn't bind to chipset model.

There *are* ways to fix the error, but Ask Ubuntu is not the correct site to ask about them. SuperUser is.